# SAGA 2.3.1 makes QGIS 2.18 crash on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, saga

On Ubuntu 18.04, using packages provided by universe repos

- QGIS 2.18.17+dfsg-1
- SAGA 2.3.1+dfsg-3build7

When starting any SAGA algorithm, QGIS crashes with a **"Segmentation fault"** error message.

We also tried to install QGIS 3.4 from https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr with both SAGA 2.3.1 (same package as above) or SAGA 7.2.0 according to https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/wiki/Compiling%20SAGA%20on%20Linux/ ...
In both cases, QGIS can't find SAGA.

We also tried to specify the path to SAGA lib by editing `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/saga.conf`

> /usr/local/lib/saga

It didn't help.

What is the setup to make QGIS work with SAGA on this OS ?

Comment: Have you tried packages from the ubuntugis-unstable ppa?

Comment: No. This is for stable teaching env purpose. We're not using such 'unstable' usually.

Comment: In this case it works (at least for me). Saga 7.2.0 is not supported by QGIS.

Comment: You mean both QGIS and SAGA installed from that unstable PPA?
Is it considered to be stable for a classroom? Would it be safe to suggest that method to the students to install on their own laptops?

Comment: I just tested with QGIS 3.4.2 installed from qgis.org/ubuntu some time ago and SAGA 2.3.1 from the main ubuntu repo and don't get a crash either. So I'm not sure what's wrong on your side.

Comment: It is odd that Saga NextGen Plugin for QGIS requires Saga 7.2.0 binaries and someone said it is not supported, what to do then?